# NoSQL. Можно ли его применять в моем случае. Язык программирования c#

Tags: nosql, хранение-данных

Появилась практическая необходимость хранить в файловой системе некоторые, в принципе довольно простые структуры данных. Необходимы CRUD операции, желательна выборка данных при помощи запросов linq.
Важно для меня способ хранения данных - в файловой системе, причем место хранения файлов должен задавать я сам. Никакого сервера базы данных устанавливаться не должно.

Можно ли для этих целей применять NoSQL? NoSQL сам я раньше никогда не использовал, но упоминания про него встречаются повсеместно. Или NoSQL другой направленности и не решит моих проблем?

Если NoSQL подходит, какой конкретно стоит использовать.

Comment: *Никакого сервера базы данных устанавливаться не должно.* -> *Можно ли для этих целей применять NoSQL?* – **Нет.**

Comment: Ясно, буду использовать класический XML-файл. Вопрост закрыт

Comment: Используйте SQLite

Answer (score 1):

Вашу задачу можно решить средствами NoSql, такими как RavenDB\MongoDB итп т.к. они являются документориентированными. Вы так же сможете использовать Linq для осуществления запросов по вашим документам.

Другое дело, нужна ли вам еще одна БД? Например postgresql может выступать и в роли NoSQL хранилища.

Так же выбор зависит от того, сколько у вас документов, их размерность, частота обращения к ним и тп.

Comment: БД принципиально не подходят автору: "Важно для меня способ хранения данных - в файловой системе, причем место хранения файлов должен задавать я сам. Никакого сервера базы данных устанавливаться не должно."

Comment: У RavenDB например есть embeded вариант.  Там можно указать директорию.